# comparing multiple column in one table with multiple columns in another

Tags: sql, hive

`table1` has a list of **new URLs** associated with users in last week

`table2` has a list of ***verified URLs*** for each user, based on history.

I want to see if the **new URLs** match with any of the ***verified URLs*** or not and I am not able to proceed with this in *hive/sql*.

**`table1`**

```
userids   new_urls
 18       www.google.com/in
 16       www.yahoo.com/ky
 16       www.hotmail.com
```

**`table2`**

```
userids   verified_urls
 18       www.map.com
 18       www.kite.com
 16       www.hotmail.com
 16       www.kayak.com
```

In this case, only *userid 16* with URL *www.hotmail.com* should match with `table2` columns. I want to know the *userid*, *new_urls* that don't match which will be other two rows in `table1`.

Answer (score 0):

select userids,new_urls
from table1
where table1.new_urls in (select verified_urls from table2)

You should use IN (or join the table or use EXISTS) but IN probably makes the most sense to start with. Just select everything from one table where a value is IN (or NOT IN) the other table.